# How to find the range of values containing bivariate formulas under a given equation relationship?

Tags: functions

Given the known condition is:

```
x^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 1
```

How to find the range of values containing bivariate formulas under a given equation relationship?

```
(x + Sqrt[3] y)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
```

The method I use is to find the maximum and minimum values separately.

```
Minimize[{
  (x + Sqrt[3] y)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], 
  x^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 1}, {x, y}]

(* {1, {x -> -(Sqrt[3]/2), y -> 3/2}} *)

Maximize[{
  (x + Sqrt[3] y)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], 
  x^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 1}, {x, y}]

(* {2, {x -> Sqrt[3]/2, 
  y -> 2 - Sqrt[
    1 - Root[{-3 + #^2& , 
       9 - 24 # #2 + 72 #2^2 - 32 # #2^3 + 16 #2^4& }, {2, 1}]^2]}} *)
```

Is there any way to directly determine its range?

Comment: `Minimize` and `Maximize` can not determine the range of function since maybe some intermediate value does not exists. Compare with `{Maximize[y, y == 2 x && ( -1 <= x <= 0 || 1 <= x <= 2), {x, y}],
 Minimize[y, y == 2 x && ( -1 <= x <= 0 || 1 <= x <= 2), {x, y}], 
 FunctionRange[{2 x, -1 <= x <= 0 || 1 <= x <= 2}, x, y]}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FunctionRange[{(x + Sqrt[3] y)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], 
  x^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 1}, {x, y}, z]
```

> `1 <= z <= 2`.

Or

```
conditions = 
  Exists[{x, y}, 
   x^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 1 && z == (x + Sqrt[3] y)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]];
Resolve[conditions, Reals]
Reduce[conditions, Reals]
```

> `1 <= z <= 2`.

### Comment

`Minimize` and `Maximize` can not determine the range of function since maybe some intermediate value does not exists.

```
Maximize[y, y == 2 x && (-1 <= x <= 0 || 1 <= x <= 2), {x, y}]

Minimize[y, y == 2 x && (-1 <= x <= 0 || 1 <= x <= 2), {x, y}]
 
FunctionRange[{2 x, -1 <= x <= 0 || 1 <= x <= 2}, x, y]
```

The range of the function is `-2 <= y <= 0 || 2 <= y <= 4` instead of between the `MinValue` and `MaxValue`, `-2<=y<=4`.

Comment: Also, `#[{(x + Sqrt[3] y)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], x^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 1}, {x, y}] & /@ {MinValue, MaxValue}`