Verify whether the function is symmetric about $x = \pi/8$
Why am I unable to get the correct result when setting up a method to verify whether the function is symmetric about the line $x = \pi/8$?
w = 2;
f[x_] = Abs[Sin[w x]] + Cos[w x]
symmetry[d_] := Simplify[f[π/8 + d] == f[π/8 - d]]
symmetryTest = ForAll[d, d ∈ Reals, symmetry[d]]
symmetryResult = Resolve[symmetryTest]


I don't see your effort in understanding the answers you've obtained: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/289341/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/290127/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/288822/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/287759/1871 (-1)

We see that it is symmetric by x==Pi, Pi/2, 0 but not for x==Pi/8.
w = 2;
f[x_] := Abs[Sin[w x]] + Cos[w x];

FullSimplify[f[Pi + x] == f[Pi - x]] === True
FullSimplify[f[Pi/2 + x] == f[Pi/2 - x]] === True
FullSimplify[f[0 + x] == f[0 - x]] === True

FullSimplify[f[Pi/8 + x] == f[Pi/8 - x]] === True


True

True

True

False

